# Why callback function gets called even though I never invoked?

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout

I wonder why this simple callback function (setTimout) gets called even though I didn't invoke but just assigned it.

In this code, I assinged setTimeout function to variable foo.

So I believe a returned value should be stored in variable foo

And It doesn't need to be executed and print 'hello' because I didn't call that function.

But why It gets called and print 'hello'?? What if I just want to assign and store it to variable??

Also How this function can be a number type and returned value is 2 ??

```
const foo = setTimeout(() => console.log('hello'), 2000);
// hello ( after 2 seconds )

console.log(typeof foo);
// number

console.log(foo);
// 2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The setTimeout is being called immediately and the timeout’s ID is being assigned to foo. You might has forgotten `() =>` before the setTimeout.

Comment: you should read the documentation a little more carefully. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

To declare it a function to be called later:

```
const foo = function () {
    setTimeout(() => console.log('hello'), 2000);
}
```

The return value of setTimeout is an integer Id for the timeout that can be used later with clearTimeout();

e.g.

```
var t = setTimeout(() => console.log('hello'), 2000);
// clear the time out
clearTimeout(t);
```

Comment: Note that the return value of `setTimeout` is the id of the timeout. In most browsers it's normally implemented as a number but it does not have to be a number. Node.js for example returns a complicated object representing the timeout

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` invokes it. That's why it's called a **call**back. Another more common word for "invoke" is "call" so a callback is basically an invokeback: someone will invoke your code later.

Here's an example of code that accept a callback:

```
function foo (cb) {
   // this function prints "foo" if callback returns true

   if (cb()) { // foo() invoking cb()!

      console.log('foo');

   }
}
```

As you can see, the programmer who writes the function is the one who invokes/calls your function. You just need to define the function that they are going to call:

```
foo(function() { return true })
```

Answer (score 0):

You just invoked the function with two parameters and stored the return result of setTimeout

```js
const foo = setTimeout(() => console.log('hello'), 2000);//
```

**Example:**
I have a function setTimeout1

```js
function setTimeout1(parm1, parm2){
  // do somthing
  return "Invoked";
}

const foo = setTimeout1(() => console.log('hello'), 2000);
```